# sorting nested list for uls with 0 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-lists

I'm trying to implement a sortable nested list, here is my progress so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ECKt8/)

It works fine when moving elements from one level to another as long as the target level has at least 1 element. But I can't move a `li` element into an empty `ul`.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>
        <span>Parent A</span>
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li>
                <span>Child A</span>
                <ul class="sortable"> </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Child B</span>
                <ul class="sortable"> </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith:'.sortable',
    placeholder: "ui-state-error",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true
});

$(".sortable").disableSelection();
```

In the code above, I want to move `Child A` into `Child B`. How can I detect the desired empty `ul` and achieve my goal? what workarounds are there?

I read all similar topics and I tried all sorts of plugins but couldn't get any to work for my tree.

Comment: I don't see empty ul and works fine for me.

Comment: @C-linkNepal You can move `Child A` inside `Child B` in my fiddle?

Comment: The ul has no dimensions because is empty and no style giving any kind of dimensions, that why you can't "detected" it. Maybe you could implement and option for de lie:hover or a min-height in the ul.sortable and/or a min-height at the li:hover ul.sortable?

Comment: @frikinside I knew what caused the problem, but I didn't know about `li:hover ul sortable`.This solved my problem. Post it as an answer and I shall accept it. Thanks

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin did it! Glad it helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ul has no dimensions because is empty and no style giving any kind of dimensions, thats why you can't "detected" it.
Maybe you could implement and option for the `li:hover` or a `min-height` in the `ul.sortable` and/or a `min-height` at the `li:hover ul.sortable`

For example:

```
li:hover ul.sortable {
    min-height:10px;
}
```